# Is this logarithmic true?

Tags: logarithms

$$x^{\log_{10}\left(\frac{y}{z}\right)}y^{\log_{10}\left(\frac{z}{x}\right)}z^{\log_{10}\left(\frac{x}{y}\right)}=1$$

for $x, y, z>0$.

Please help me I couldn't figure this out for the life of me.

Answer (score 4):

You have

$$x^{\log_{10}(y/z)}=x^{\log_{10}(y)-\log_{10}(z)}=\frac{x^{\log_{10}(y)}}{x^{\log_{10}(z)}}.$$

So you get

$$x^{\log_{10}(y/z)}y^{\log_{10}(z/x)}z^{\log_{10}(x/y)}=\frac{x^{\log_{10}(y)}y^{\log_{10}(z)}z^{\log_{10}(x)}}{x^{\log_{10}(z)}y^{\log_{10}(x)}z^{\log_{10}(y)}}=1.$$

Answer (score 3):

Hint. Recall [basic properties of the logarithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_logarithmic_identities).
Since $a^b=10^{b\cdot\log_{10} (a)}$ then we have that
$$x^{\log_{10}\left(\frac{y}{z}\right)}=10^{(\log_{10}(y)-\log_{10}(z))\cdot\log_{10}(x)}$$
Manipulate the other terms in a similar way and you should obtain that the final exponent of $10$ is zero.

Comment: The term on the right is $1$, so I don't know where you got that from. Are you assuming the equality is true?

Comment: @Señor Billy Sorry I corrected a typo.

Comment: THANK YOU VERY MUCH. I finally did it after 2 hours :)

Answer (score 3):

$x^ {(\log_{10}y- \log_{10}z)} * y^ {(\log_{10}z - \log_{10}x)} * z ^{( \log_{10}x - \log_{10}y)} = 1$

Introducing $\log$ to each term,
\begin{align*}
\implies & \log[x^ {(\log_{10}y- \log_{10}z)} * y^ {(\log_{10}z - \log_{10}x)} * z ^{( \log_{10}x - \log_{10}y)}] = \log_{10}1\\
\\
\implies& \log_{10}x^ {(\log_{10}y- \log_{10}z)} + \log_{10}y^ {(\log_{10}z - \log_{10}x)} + \log_{10}z ^{( \log_{10}x - \log_{10}y)} = \log_{10}1\\
\\
\implies& ( \log_{10}y- \log_{10}z) \log_{10}x + (\log_{10}z - \log_{10}x) \log_{10}y + (\log_{10}x - \log_{10}y) \log_{10}z = 0\\
\\
\implies&\log_{10}x \cdot \log_{10}y - \log_{10}x \cdot \log_{10}z + \log_{10}y \cdot \log_{10}z - \log_{10}x  \cdot \log_{10}y +\log_{10}x \cdot\log_{10}z  \\ &- \log_{10}y \cdot \log_{10}z = 0\\
\\
\implies & 0 = 0\end{align*}

Comment: Wow, I had never heard of "antilog." Why does such a name exist.... It already has a perfectly good name.

Comment: When you "introduce log to each term" you use $\log(A+B) = \log(A) + \log(B)$ - but that's not true! If you can't fix your method you should probably delete your attempt.

Comment: @mrob see http://www.math-only-math.com/antilogarithm.html

Comment: Sorry in typing I skip one step.

Comment: Its totally ok thank u.

Answer (score 1):

$$
\begin{align}
\log_{10}\left(x^{\log_{10}\left(\frac yz\right)}y^{\log_{10}\left(\frac zx\right)}z^{\log_{10}\left(\frac xy\right)}\right)
&=\log_{10}(x)\left(\log_{10}(y)-\log_{10}(z)\right)\\
&+\log_{10}(y)\left(\log_{10}(z)-\log_{10}(x)\right)\\
&+\log_{10}(z)\left(\log_{10}(x)-\log_{10}(y)\right)\\[3pt]
&=0
\end{align}
$$